# Error : Not unique table/alias: 'm3' in MySQL

Tags: mysql

```
Not unique table/alias: 'm3'


SELECT count(distinct e.guid) as total 
From elgg_entities e JOIN elgg_metadata m ON e.guid = m.entity_guid 
                     JOIN elgg_metadata m2 ON e.guid = m2.entity_guid 
                     JOIN elgg_metadata m3  ON (e.guid = m3.entity_guid) 
                     JOIN elgg_metadata m3 ON (e.guid = m3.entity_guid) 
                     JOIN elgg_metastrings v ON v.id = m.value_id 
                     JOIN elgg_metastrings v2 ON v2.id = m2.value_id
WHERE e.type='object' AND 
      e.subtype=32 AND
      m3.name_id='120908' AND 
      m3.value_id='1399' AND 
      m3.name_id='145634' AND 
      m3.value_id='145635' AND 
      e.site_guid = 1 AND 
      ((1 = 1) AND e.enabled='yes' OR (e.owner_guid = 2 AND e.enabled='no')) AND 
      ((1 = 1) AND m.enabled='yes' OR (m.owner_guid = 2 AND m.enabled='no')) AND 
      ((1 = 1) and m2.enabled='yes' OR (m2.owner_guid = 2 AND m2.enabled='no'))
```

What is error in the query ? How to solve it.

Comment: `elgg_metadata m3` and then `elgg_metadata m3` again - here you go

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes... you are joining elgg_metadata two times with a alias `m3`... change it to `m4` or another alias like this

```
SELECT
    count(distinct e.guid) as total
from elgg_entities e
JOIN elgg_metadata m
    ON e.guid = m.entity_guid
JOIN elgg_metadata m2
    on e.guid = m2.entity_guid
JOIN elgg_metadata m3
    ON (e.guid = m3.entity_guid)
JOIN elgg_metadata spongebob ON (e.guid = spongebob.entity_guid)
JOIN elgg_metastrings v on v.id = m.value_id JOIN elgg_metastrings v2 on v2.id = m2.value_id
WHERE e.type='object' and e.subtype=32 and m3.name_id='120908' and m3.value_id='1399' and m3.name_id='145634' and m3.value_id='145635' and e.site_guid = 1 and ( (1 = 1) and e.enabled='yes' OR (e.owner_guid = 2 AND e.enabled='no')) and ( (1 = 1) and m.enabled='yes' OR (m.owner_guid = 2 AND m.enabled='no')) and ( (1 = 1) and m2.enabled='yes' OR (m2.owner_guid = 2 AND m2.enabled='no'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using alias name **m3** two times here

```
 JOIN elgg_metadata m3  ON (e.guid = m3.entity_guid) 
 JOIN elgg_metadata m3 ON (e.guid = m3.entity_guid)
```